# Help verifying this proof for Analysis. Its from the book 'Understanding Analysis'.

Tags: real-analysis

Question: If $ A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq A_3 \supseteq...\supseteq A_n $ are all sets containing an infinite number of elements then $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty } A_n$
is infinite as well.

Counterexample:
Let,

- $A_1 = \left \{ 1,2,3,... \right \}$
- $A_2 = \left \{ 2,4,6,... \right \}$
- $A_3 = \left \{ 3,6,9,... \right \}$
- and $A_n = \left \{ n,2n,3n,... \right \}$

Clearly, $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq ...\supseteq \bigcap_n A_n=\varnothing$
since each element in $A_1$ fails to be present in at least one $A_n$.

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the statement is wrong, and you have the right idea, but note that for example $A_2 \not\supset A_3$, as $3 \not\in A_2$.

But, you can repair this easily, let, for example 
$$ A_n = \{n, n+1, n+2, \ldots\}$$
Then $A_1 \supseteq A_2 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq A_n$, and $\bigcap_n A_n = \emptyset$.

Comment: There is not such statement in Abbott's book. It is a question where the student must decide whether the claim is true or false. In this case it is false, of course.